# How to get the latest NuGet Packages during TFS2013 build

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I've got a local build getting the correct NuGet packages before a build but my TFS (2013) build still fails. How do I get the latest packages before the TFS build kicks off?

I've read several articles that talk about deleting the NuGet.targets file from the solution, but I don't understand how the solution can possibly know to look in our local NuGet store to get the packages if I do that???

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#command-line-restore) article I've added "$(SolutionDir)\nuget restore" to the pre-build event of the first project in the solution to be built, but that doesn't seem to be working.

**@Bikerdude - Update 8/14/17**

Nope - nothing on the process tab:
[image]

Comment: XAML build supported automatic NuGet package restore without any additional actions on your part. Look at the detailed logs of your build and search for "NuGet" -- you should see where it attempts to restore them and presumably fails. Make sure your build server has access to nuget.org. Also ensure that you're building a solution file, not a project file.

Comment: You can refer to this article to call NuGet.exe by using InvokeProcess activity (Custom build template): [TFS Build Restore NuGet Packages](https://automatetheplanet.com/integrate-nuget-package-restore-tfs-build/).